# Xmodmap syntax for rebinding Shift+Down to Up

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I would like to rebind some keys on Linux via Xmodmap. Left and up cursor on my Acer (yes, I know) laptop have broke. I would like to map shift+down to up, and shift+right to left. Struggling to determine the syntax for this from man pages. This syntax is wrong, throws bad modifier, but captures the intent:

```
add Shift_L+Down = Up
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
keysym Down = Down Up
```

to do that. The `keysym` value is an ordered list of keysyms to use when unmodified, shifted, switched, shifted and switched, AltGr+key, shift-AltGr+key (all optional). Here unmodified <kbd>Down</kbd> is itself, while <kbd>Shift-Down</kbd> is bound to <kbd>Up</kbd>, and we don't set anything for the switched or AltGr modes.

There is a remaining problem: the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is still pressed, so <kbd>Shift-Down</kbd> will be treated by applications the same way as <kbd>Shift-Up</kbd>. That may not be a problem for your use cases, but if you're going to use something that, say, uses shifted arrows for text selection, you'll have a problem. In that case there is another option:

```
keysym Down = Down Down Up Up
```

That binds both <kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Down</kbd> as <kbd>Down</kbd>, and <kbd>Mode_switch-Down</kbd> and <kbd>Mode_switch-Shift-Down</kbd> to <kbd>Up</kbd>. Applications are unlikely to be listening to the <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> key in the same way they do to <kbd>Shift</kbd>, so you don't get the double behaviour.

You then need to bind something to the `Mode_switch` keysym. I use:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
```

which, on my keyboard, replaces <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, a key I don't have a use for. <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> now gives me <kbd>Up</kbd> as far as all my applications are concerned. You could rebind one of your shift keys instead if you preferred, but you'd lose the ordinary <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier behaviour when you did.

---

There are actually more levels you can bind if you need, which use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, and depending on your layout there can be yet another set of changes available. XCompose may also be useful to you.