# How to map S-Up to Down?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

The `down` key on my laptop is broken.  I want to map `shift+up` to `down`.  My original layout had (from `xmodmap -pke`)

```
keycode 111 = Up    NoSymbol Up
keycode 113 = Left  NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 116 = Down  NoSymbol Down
```

To be on the safe side, let us set `up+all mods` to `down`:

```
keycode 111 = Up    Down Down Down Down Down
```

Indeed, `xev` shows `keysym down` when I press `up` while holding `shift` (`xev` output from pressing `down`, then `shift+up` is included below); but applications do not react properly (e.g., Firefox acts as to normal `shift+up`, in the terminal I get `[1;2B` which *is* different from unmodified `shift+up` (`[1;2A`)).  It does not work with other modifier combinations either.

I also tried `keysym Down = Down Up` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179804/xmodmap-syntax-for-rebining-shiftup), but that did not work either.

---

*Edit for clarification:* My approach and the answer to the linked question do not work for me because some applications (Firefox and Thunderbird for example) react to the re-mapped `shift*down` as if `shift+up` had been pressed, not `up` alone.  In addition, my terminal emulator prints `[1;2B` instead.

Alternatively, I tried remapping the left `shift` and `control` keys to `down`; this works in the terminal, but e.g. Firefox still responds as to `shift+up` or `control+up`, respectively.

---

`xev` output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4024962, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4025234, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4027956, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4028076, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x1, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 116
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4028150, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x1, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 116
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 4028228, (-429,376), root:(215,396),
    state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Your xev output does indicate it is working, with the same caveats as mentioned in the other question.

Comment: @michaelhomer indeed, I messed up that link. Anyway, your answer there does not work for me, hence my question. I will try restarting Firefox, but honestly I do not think that should be relevant. Note that it reacted as for s-up, not s-down, and that using another modifier did not help either.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's relevant or not, if it didn't restart it won't pick up changes (I tried it). In any case, it's a duplicate either way.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Funny, on my machine all programs that I tried react immediately, restarting makes no difference.  Anyway, I tried to clarify why your answer to the other question (and my own approach) does not work.

Comment: Fully 80% of that answer is discussing exactly that issue.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I finally got around to giving this another try. Turns out, your suggestion with `Mode_switch` does work! Before, I tried with `ISO_Level3_Shift` (I had not bound `Mode_switch`) but for some reason, that does *not* work.  Anyway, thank you.